# Cannot hear the audio when I don't connect the laptop with the bluetooth speaker

Tags: audio, bluetooth, device

The Bluetooth always connects to the laptop audio. If we don't connect, we cannot hear the sound or audio. When I found out the problem, It appears that the DNS server is not responding.

Want to hear the sound audio from laptop even though I don't connect the Bluetooth speaker.